# Repeat array of of users as links joined by commas, without trailing comma

Tags: angularjs

I'm just getting started with Angular, so I'm really not sure how to solve this problem.

I'm importing a list of private messages (from Mongo) in which there is a subobject of recipients in the following format:

```
"recipients": [{
    "userID": 1,
    "username": "User1",
    "read": false
},
{
    "userID": 2,
    "username": "User2",
    "read": false
}]
```

I want to format them into user links: `<a href="/user/1/">User1</a>, <a href="/user/2/">User2</a>`

I wasn't sure how to do this straight in the view, so I thought to add it to the controller in the $http function as:

```
var recipientList = new Array();
value.recipients.forEach(function(value, key) {
    recipientList.push("<a href=\"/user/" + value.userID + "/\" class=\"username\">" + value.username + "</a>");
});
data[key].recipients = recipientList.join(', ');
```

But when I display it {{pm.recipients}}, it shows up as a string instead of HTML.

I've been thinking of wrapping it in a span, then using ng-repeat in an a tag, but I'm not sure how to get it to display commas between them, but not in the last.

Advice? Should this be on the view logic or controller logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need to write any kind of markup in within your controller. Directives are for DOM manipulation. In this case, you just need to use some databinding and built in directives:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.recipients = [{
    "userID": 1,
    "username": "User1",
    "read": false
  },
  {
    "userID": 2,
    "username": "User2",
    "read": false
  }];
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <a ng-repeat="user in recipients" ng-href="/user/{{user.userID}}/">
    {{user.username}}{{!$last ? ',' : ''}}
  </a>
</div>
```

`ng-repeat` loops over the array of recipients, creating markup for each of them.

`ng-href` just delays the application of the `href` attribute until the data is available, which is a better than it would do with just databinding right in the `href` tag.

For the comma, you just need to use the `$last` variable provided in `ng-repeat`. You could do this a few ways. I like `{{!$last ? ',' : ''}}` which is just ternary for "if not the last item, bind a comma, otherwise, bind nothing."

The reason your markup appeared as a string is because databinding will only display everything as a string. To bind a string as HTML, you have to use the `ng-bind-html` directive. However, Angular doesn't trust HTML by default and will not bind it unless you use the `$sce` service to specifically allow it. It's a bit of a task, but like I said, you don't need that here anyway.

Reply to your comment, to take the comma out of the anchor:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in recipients">
  <a ng-href="/user/{{user.userID}}/">{{user.username}}</a>
  <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking of this, but I couldn't figure out the comma issue. I want to have a comma after each link, but not after the last (a comma separated list of links).

Comment: @RhoVisions oh, I just saw that! Will have that updated in a second! Easy stuff!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually wrote that code at first too, but it places the comma in the link, which while generally fine, isn't symantically correct. No way to put it outside? I guess I could repeat spans surrounding the links, but that's a LOT of markup. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @RhoVisions Sure, just ng-repeat a wrapping element and put the comma outside of the anchor. I'll update again :/

Comment: Don't worry about it, I understand how to do that. I was just concerned it was a lot of markup for just a list of items.

Comment: @RhoVisions nah, it's normal. A lot prettier than writing strings of html in the controller! =D